# ostream.h: No such file or directory

Tags: c++, c, include, legacy, ostream

I'm trying to update an older project using a newer compiler and newer tools (New version of vxWorks but it shouldn't matter). In the code it says:

```
#include <ostream.h>
```

However I get a ton of errors back, most of them stemming from:

```
ostream.h: No such file or directory
```

I looked up the error and a lot of solutions said to change it to:

```
#include "ostream"
```

This works, however this is legacy code and I'd rather not go into changing all of these. Is there a way I can change these includes without changing the code?

Comment: C++ was standardized in 1998.  Do yourself and your future self a favor and fix your legacy code to comply with the standard.  You will pay the cost once and reap the benefits forever.  Just my $0.02.

Comment: Use `<>` for standard headers.

Comment: Legacy code is likely to have other problems which won't be papered over so easily. For example, if the legacy code relies on the compiler being lax about two-phase name lookup, how will you get it to work with a modern compiler that's not as lax as older compilers without changing the code? You should really consider just fixing the code rather than trying to make non-standard code work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, you could create a file named `ostream.h` which consists only of a single line:

```
#include <ostream>
```

Comment: Well my only problem with that is this code was just revised less than a week ago, and I'm sure not everyone is using an old compiler. Is there a way to go about this maybe using paths or something?

Comment: This fixes the immediate problem, however the API changed also, so code changes are probably needed.

Comment: With that approach, you'll also want `using namespace std;`, since the ancient headers put everything in the global namespace. Personally, I'd recommend modernising the code instead.

Comment: The key point is do the proper job with that proper tool.

c++90 != c++98 != c++11.

The best way to compile "old code" is use an "old compiler" (or a compiler following the "old standard").

Compiling pre'98 code with post'03 compilers will always have some potential disaster hidden inside.